# In Ruby, how do I sort the elements in a hash by the quantity of words in the keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

For example:

```
{"job" => 1, "big job" => 2, "super job" => 1, "work" => 2, "super big job" => 1}
```

I want to turn into something like this

```
{"super big job" => 1, "big job" => 2, "super job" => 1, "job" => 1, , "work" => 2}
```

i.e., three-word key goes first, then two-word keys, one-word keys go last.
I understand that I can count the words using key.split(' ').length function, but how can I use it to actually modify the order of elements in the hash.

Comment: ... Why do you want the results in a hash? While Ruby hashes are ordered *now*, they weren't in the past. Return them in something more naturally ordered, like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
a = {"job" => 1, "big job" => 2, "super job" => 1, "work" => 2, "super big job" => 1}
Hash[a.sort_by { |k, v| k.split.size }.reverse]
# => {"super big job"=>1, "super job"=>1, "big job"=>2, "work"=>2, "job"=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {"job" => 1, "big job" => 2, "super job" => 1, "work" => 2, "super big job" => 1}

p  x.sort_by{|x,|-x.split.size}.to_h #=> {"super big job"=>1, "big job"=>2, "super job"=>1, "work"=>2, "job"=>1}
```